# Not accurately read numeric number with a DataReader from SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite

I got a problem where I can't read the data from my database correctly.

To give you an example, I got the important value that is in the database **6.69879289850025E-06**, but I read **6.0** (which is not accurate since it's suppose to be way smaller) in the C# program.

Something similar happen to ImportantValue2 where the value that is in the database is -**0,000158976621370616** and in my C# program I get **0,0**.

```
 public double ImportantValue1 { get; set; }
 public double ImportantValue2 { get; set; }
 public string Note { get; set; }


public MyObject(SQLiteDataReader reader)
        {
            ImportantValue1 = Convert.ToDouble(reader["important_value_1"]); //Value in the database is REAL
            ImportantValue2 = Convert.ToDouble(reader["important_value_2"]);//Value in the database is REAL
            Note = reader["note"].ToString(); //Value in the database is TEXT
        }
```

***Update***

And this is how I call it.

```
using (SQLiteConnection c = new SQLiteConnection(connection))
{
    c.Open();
    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sqlCommand, c))
    {
        using (SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                objectFromBD = new MyObject(reader);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the SQLite code

```
CREATE TABLE "table"(
    "id" INTEGER,
    "important_value_1" REAL NOT NULL,
    "important_value_2" REAL NOT NULL,
    "note" TEXT NOT NULL,
    
    PRIMARY KEY ("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Just to clarify that I also tried to do `(double)reader["important_value_2"]`

Answer (score 0):

`reader["important_value_1"]` will return index which column exists in your SQL script instead of your expectation value.

> `reader["important_value_1"]` will get the value of the specified column.

You can try to use `reader["important_value_1"]` in `reader.GetDouble` function to read your data from columns.

```
ImportantValue1  = reader.GetDouble(reader["important_value_1"])
ImportantValue2  = reader.GetDouble(reader["important_value_2"])
```

[SqliteDataReader.Item[] Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite.sqlitedatareader.item?view=msdata-sqlite-6.0.0#microsoft-data-sqlite-sqlitedatareader-item(system-int32))

**Note**

You might need to use `reader.Read()` let the reader point to read the next row if you want.

```
while (reader.Read()){
   //... read all rows from your db
}
```

Comment: For some reason, I can't read anything from `reader.GetDouble(1)`. I get an InvalidCastException if I try.

Comment: What's your full SQL script? and I would suggest you write the db connection action in the same method instead of pass the `reader` to use

Comment: Ok I just found out I can reader.GetString(1) and get the correct value in a string.

Comment: I updated my post @D-Shih

Answer (score 0):

Here is a temporary solution I got, but that is not efficient.

I saw that I can read a string with the reader, but I couldn't do it with a double. So I used `reader.GetString(rowValue);` and than I converted the string to a double using the fonction below.

```
public double StringToDoubleWithNotation(string value)
{
    return Convert.ToDouble(Decimal.Parse(value, NumberStyles.AllowExponent | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint));
}
```

Now everything is fine, but I would prefer to see a better solution since doing 3 conversion is not that efficient.